# Is is possible to load .coffee script file to browser and execute?

Tags: coffeescript

I am trying to load coffee script inside a sample.coffee file along with the coffee-script.js file and perform some simple operations on the HTML. But i am not able to load the sample.coffee file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="sample.coffee" type="text/coffeescript"></script>      
    <script src="coffee-script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the coffeescript code inside sample.coffee

```
message = "Welcome to Coffeescript"
alert message
```

I referred the blog http://forgivingworm.wordpress.com/2010/09/27/running-coffeescript-in-browser/

I trying to run this in MVC4 project on .cshtml. So I am running under MS world.

I am not sure if this is possible or not? any insight into this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is in your sample.coffee file? Maybe it contains a broken script.
Can you share it?
Your sample code above works fine in Firefox.

Comment: have added the coffeescript code in sample.coffee. Inline coffeescript will work. Also i figured IIS is not able to identify the .coffee extension. So i am able to get this work now with CoffeeSharp http://tomlokhorst.github.com/CoffeeSharp/ which gives the handler for for .coffee files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to solve this issue by using the CoffeeSharp http://tomlokhorst.github.com/CoffeeSharp/ It gives handler for .coffee files also converts the coffeescript to javascript on the browser.

Also I am able to compile the coffeescript to javascript during the build event itself which solves deployment and performance related issues.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think this will work like you tried it. 
You will need something like requirejs and the coffeescript loader 
at https://github.com/jrburke/require-cs.

However I would strongly discourage this and rather have it compiled before loading into the browser (require.js is encouraged though). You might find grunt.js helpful for "building" your app before deploying.

Answer (score 0):

That html works fine for me.  I used the `coffee-script.js` found here: https://cdn.rawgit.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/1.11.1/extras/coffee-script.js and my `sample.coffee` is:

```
x = ->
  alert("hi")

x()
```

If you open the Javascript console, do you see any errors?

Comment: I got the error for missing mime type in chrome and IIS is not able to handle the .coffee extension. I am able to solve these issues using CoffeeSharp http://tomlokhorst.github.com/CoffeeSharp/