# How do I run coffeescript in browser?

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

I want to write my jQuery with CoffeeScript. I can't manage to get CoffeeScript to run in the browser though. What should I do?

**index.html**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script  type="text/coffeescript" src="app.coffee"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/raw/master/extras/coffee-script.js"> </script>
```

I tried switching my script tags around:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="javascript" src="http://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/raw/master/extras/coffee-script.js"> </script>
<script  type="text/coffeescript" src="app.coffee"></script>
```

But the coffeescript in app.coffee is still not running:

```
$(document).ready ->
  console.log "works"
```

Additionally, I receive the following message in console:

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain:
```

Comment: You need to change order of `app.coffee` and `coffee-script.js`. `coffee-script.js` should be called before `app.coffee`

Comment: Still not working. Check edit

Comment: Console is empty and no errors?

Comment: I receive the following message: "Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain:"

Comment: possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15742415/is-is-possible-to-load-coffee-script-file-to-browser-and-execute

Answer (score 2):

Github sets the `X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff` header to prevent using Github as a CDN (in compliant browsers). But with that being said, I'm going to go out on a limb and say you are accessing via `file://` or `c:\`, in which there is another caveat; the browser is going to prevent you from loading your coffeescript file on account of the cross-origin policy.

So, your best bet is actually to use something like [Harp](http://harpjs.com/) and set up a simple development server, or compile your coffeescript to javascript.