# How to compile an external Coffeescript file to HTML?

Tags: html, coffeescript

I have a HTML file, which I want to link to an external Coffeescript file (the CS file is called `main.coffee`). I tried doing this:

`<script type="text/coffeescript" src="main.coffee"></script>`

But it didn't work. What's wrong?

I have Coffeescript installed through NPM, if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

write this inside the header

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
```

write this inside the body

```
<script type="text/coffeescript">
//  write what you need to do
</script>
```

Comment: you need to convert coffee to javascript. then You can use my code.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers do not support coffeescript, and npm is a tool for installing JS libraries (and executables) for NodeJS not for browsers.

You need to use the coffee script program you installed with npm to turn your coffeescript source into JavaScript:

```
coffee -c main.coffee
```

… and then use that JS in your page:

```
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

CoffeeScript needs to be compiled to Javascript before loading the script in your HTML.

You can get this job done with the `coffee` command itself.

```
coffee -c main.coffee
```

Anyway, I'd recommend you to automate this build process with a build system/task runner like [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/), [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/), etc.

You'll find plenty of tutorials for doing this. For example: [Starting with Gulp.js & CoffeeScript](http://thibaudb.com/starting-with-gulp-coffeescript/)

Comment: Ah, thanks! So there's no such thing as doing what I did?

Comment: In fact, it is possible (See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15742415/is-is-possible-to-load-coffee-script-file-to-browser-and-execute)), but I'd strongly recommend not to do it this way.

Comment: That could work. Also, how does the tutorial help with automatically compiling CS code?

Comment: Take a look at [Building With Gulp](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/06/building-with-gulp/), more specifically at *watching* files in order to automate things.